# 'Voice' object has no attribute 'voice_clients'

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I get a error in this function:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

class Voice(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(name='join')
    async def join(self, ctx):
        voice = discord.utils.get(self.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        print(voice)

    @commands.command(name='leave')
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        pass

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Voice(client))
```

Error is:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: AttributeError: 'Voice' object has no attribute
> 'voice_clients'

I dont know why I get the error, would be very nice, if someone can help me with this

Comment: Your Voice object simply doesnt have the voice_clients value as you never define it. It seems like you are looking for client.voice_clients though, which you could get by using self.client.voice_clients

Comment: If I just make 
print(self.client.voice_clients)
I get a empty list ...

Comment: Are you connect to any voice channels?

Comment: yes, i tryied if I was in and out, both print empty list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never defined `voice_clients`, it's `self.client.voice_clients`. Also you can simply use `Guild.voice_client` or even easier - `Context.voice_client`

```py
voice = ctx.voice_client
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_client)
- [`Context.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20voice#discord.ext.commands.Context.voice_client)

Comment: Make this 

`    @commands.command(name='join')
    async def join(self, ctx):
        voice = ctx.voice_client
        print(voice)`

Print None, if I am in a voice channel :/